# Use Eclipse classpath variables in Java code

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, classpath

Is it possible to use Eclipse's classpath variables within in Java code? I have several bin directories for multiple projects that are defined in classpath variables, and need to reference them multiple times within one of my projects.

Comment: Do you always want to use your IDE to run your programs?

Comment: Not generally, but in this case Eclipse is an integral part of our final deliverable to our client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tying something unique to an IDE to your application code is not particularly good practice. Try instead to make use of system properties, environment variables or the `-D` arguments to the application.

Comment: Note that system properties and -D arguments are the same thing :-)

Comment: Yes, very much. Thanks for noting that. It's just that we can set them conditionally in our program whereas can't do the same with `-D` arguments.

Comment: Eclipse is going to be a required tool for the final deliverable to our client, so in this case the IDE will always be present. I ended up just adding the required output folders to the classpath as recommended above.